# server backend crash issue on "findOneAndUpdate" change

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

i am a newbie developer and i have a problem, please forgive my english.
my code is supposed to create the bio and modify it but each time the server crashes when I call my PUT route on Postman can you help me? here is the piece of code:

```
exports.updateUser = async (req, res) => {
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
    return res.status(400).send("ID unknown : " + req.params.id);

  try {
    await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      {
        $set: {
          bio: req.body.bio,
        },
      },
      { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true },
      (err, data) => {
        if (!err) return res.send(data);
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: err });
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

Comment: what is error message? Have you define route as `put`?

Comment: Please share the error message. One obvious thing that you are doing wrong is using both the callback API of mongoose and also using `await`. Either remove the callback passed to `UserModel.findOneAndUpdate` or remove the `await` keyword. If you remove the callback function, move the code inside that callback function, after the `UserModel.findOneAndUpdate()` call.

Comment: e is the error message on the postman : {
    "message": {
        "originalStack": "Error\n    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOneAndUpdate]